# Figuring AWS API Gateway GetUsage - Numbers don't balance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We are querying [API Gateway GetUsage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_GetUsage.html) and numbers don't seem to balance.

We have a usage plan with 35,000,000 calls per month. When we query the endpoint, the result we get for **the first day** is `[1087939, 33809935]`. According to the documentation, this maps to `[used quota, remaining quota].`.

So, I would assume that, in my case, `35,000,000 - used quota = remaining quota`. But it does not. `35,000,000 - 1,087,939 = 33,912,061` and not `33,809,935` as reported by the endpoint response.

Which of these numbers is wrong?

Also, to spice things up, if we sum up the `use quota` for every day, the api key we are looking at goes over the quota ~6 days before it started to be throttled. The documentation states that API plans quota are not strongly enforced, but still, I would expect them to be enforced within the same day, not many days after.